# Can i disable link local IPv4 address assignment in route table Ubuntu 16.04 permanently

Tags: ipv4, link-local

I am having trouble with disabling link local IPv4 address getting added in my routing table.

So far i have uninstalled, avahi-daemon, commented out link-local 169.254.0.0 line in /etc/networks file , but still when DHCP client fails, i see that in my IPv4 routing table an entry is created using 169.254.x.x address.

I want to disable this behavior permanently in my ubuntu 16.04 OS.

How can i do this?

Comment: You can assign addresses manually.

Comment: Hello Michael, i did that in /etc/network/interfaces file, but still i see an entry of link-local IP in IPv4 routing table. So when i type ifconfig, i see interface eth0 having my static IP 11.11.11.X , but when i type in command "route -n", i see an entry for 169.254.0.X pointing to eth0 and another entry default pointing to Link local of eth0 .